# visual studio 2008 moc cant find mainwindow.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have a build environment set up for a bunch of C++ projects on Visual Studio 2008 that use Qt. I haven't had to recompile the code for a while, but something must have changed on my system because it doesn't work anymore.

All the environment variables are still correct, as far as I can tell, and I haven't updated Visual Studio or Qt.

The error I get is:

```
1>MOC mainwindow.h
1>The system cannot find the path specified.
1>moc: mainwindow.h: No such file
1>Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "MOC mainwindow.h"
```

and the offending line according to my build log is:

```
C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\bin\moc.exe  -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"..\..\..\..\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\..\..\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include" -I"..\..\LSL\liblsl\bin" -I"..\..\..\..\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"." -I..\..\..\..\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\mkspecs\default -D_MSC_VER=1500 -DWIN32 mainwindow.h -o debug\moc_mainwindow.cpp
```

(sorry so long). It shows that moc.exe is getting called, but it can't find mainwindow.h (which is in the directory of the project, and is definitely an included directory).

I re-ran qmake `qmake -project` (thanks J-Mik!), but now it is hanging on uic

```
1>UIC mainwindow.ui
1>The system cannot find the path specified.
1>File 'mainwindow.ui' is not valid
1>Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "UIC mainwindow.ui"
```

The file is certainly valid (it opens in Qt creator). What is also odd is that the build log is still shooting an error about moc:

```
C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\bin\moc.exe  -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"..\..\..\..\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\..\..\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include" -I"..\..\LSL\liblsl\bin" -I"..\..\..\..\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"." -I..\..\..\..\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\mkspecs\default -D_MSC_VER=1500 -DWIN32 mainwindow.h -o debug\moc_mainwindow.cpp



if errorlevel 1 goto VCReportError

goto VCEnd

:VCReportError

echo Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "MOC mainwindow.h"

exit 1

:VCEnd
```

Comment: have you tried running qmake on your project again?

Comment: Yes, actually it did have an effect, but no joy yet. I am still having problems. I will revise the question.

Answer (score 0):

The relative path to your files is incorrect for the current directory when moc is run.  You can identify the actual directory by adding `echo %cd%` to the custom build step that is running moc.

Comment: In my vcproj file, I have these lines: `   <File
    RelativePath="mainwindow.h"
    >`

Comment: I tried adding the echo line to my build commands, still nothing. I think I may have botched something in the process of installing different versions of Qt as well as the Intel compiler. I am going to try to wipe all this stuff and reinstall it. I seriously doubt there is a problem with project itself, because I can build it on different machines using the same tools. This makes me think there is a problem with the local install of VS 2008 here. Also, I have seen people report re-installation as a solution to similar issues.

Comment: fresh install did nothing

Comment: The `echo %cd%` doesn't fix anything, it simply lets you see what the current directory is when you're running moc.  If moc says it can't find the file, then the argument you're giving moc doesn't point to an actual file.

Answer (score 0):

Removing and re-importing mainwindow.h does the trick. Now the compiler can't find the mainwindow.ui file (which uic needs).

Comment: Also, I figured out the root of the problem. It all had to do with some conflict with a file I made to alias some shell commands -- specifically invoking different versions of python, I put the answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534162/visual-studio-2008-cant-find-the-path-specified