# Visual Studio 2008 cant find the path specified

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have some projects that I haven't compiled on a particular computer for a while, although they compile fine on others -- the same exact projects, not copies. I am compiling code from the same network directory. As I said, on some computers, it works fine.

However, on the computer in my office, visual studio seems to have lost all sense of a directory structure.

First I was having trouble with moc (these projects use Qt) finding the mainwindow.h file. This is in the same directory as the .sln, .vproj, etc. I posted a question about this alread here:
[visual studio 2008 moc cant find mainwindow.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510086/visual-studio-2008-moc-cant-find-mainwindow-h)

By removing and reloading mainwindow.h into the project, moc and visual studio were able to see it.

Now moc can find mainwindow.h, but uic can't find mainwindow.ui -- which really comes as no surprise at this point. This is the error I get from visual studio:

```
1>UIC mainwindow.ui
1>The system cannot find the path specified.
1>File 'mainwindow.ui' is not valid
1>Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "UIC mainwindow.ui"
```

and here is the offending line in the build log

```
C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2008\bin\uic.exe mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
```

Now, if I cd into the directory with the solution in it, I can run this line above and it generates ui_mainwindow.h beautifully.

I am at a loss here. Clearly the files and permissions are fine, because I can compile them (although not from my local copy of visual studio). Clearly the .vcproj files are correct, because I can compile on other machines. It seems like there is some global tweak regarding paths that I somehow inadvertently did to my copy of visual studio.

Also, I reinstalled it and the same behavior persists. I figured if there was some offending config file secreted away in the Windows file structure, this would have cleaned it, but obviously not.

On the computer for which this setup does work, I get this as the first output:

```
1>UIC mainwindow.ui
1>Z:\dmedine\git-lsl-tst-wrkng\labstreaminglayer\Apps\XDFBrowser>doskey python26="C:\python26\python"  
1>MOC mainwindow.h
1>Z:\dmedine\git-lsl-tst-wrkng\labstreaminglayer\Apps\XDFBrowser>doskey python26="C:\python26\python"
```

I am a little confused by these doskey commands (I didn't create these projects, so there is much to be confused by). Does moc and uic need python on Windows? I did play around with my doskeys regarding python recently, so maybe this is the root of the problem, but I would like to know why.

Comment: Also, I tried running this on VS2010. Same issue.

Comment: I assume uic.exe is a Qt tool.  Is that set up correctly in VS on your machine?  How that external tool is set up probably has nothing to do with the VS solution or project.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, the key I added in regedit that had some aliases for calling different versions of python was indeed the culprit. Here is that file (in case anyone is curious):

```
doskey ls=dir $*
doskey python27-64=C:\Python27-64\python.exe $*
doskey python35-32=C:\python35-32\python.exe $*
```

Apparently (and I only noticed this from inspecting the working setup and noting the doskey lines) these calls to doskey destroy the moc/ui process on Windows.

This makes no sense. Also, it is quite inconvenient because now I have to work really really hard to call different versions of python.